# Show content if there's a `conversation_id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a messaging system set up so when a new `message` is created a `conversation_id` will be created for any replies associated with the `message`'s `id`.  The `conversation_id` is supposed to match the `message`'s `id`.

The question I have is how can I show every messages.body with the current conversation id? I am trying to create a threaded messaging system.

Here's a example:

I sent a message out that created message id 5 and no conversation id (The code I created does not supply a conversation id to the original message). I replied to message id 5 and had a conversation that created message ids 8, 9, 10. Those three message ids have a conversation id of 5.

When user views message id 8...in the view it should also show message id 5, 9, and 10 since it's part of the conversation and they have conversation_id as 5 (with the exception of message id 5, no conversation_id shows for it since it's the original message).

Controller:

```
  def show
    @new_message = Message.new
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
      @message.readingmessage if @message.recipient == current_user
    end
```

Comment: Show your models for message and conversation.

Comment: @Catfish message model has been added. There is no conversation model that relates to the functioning of this inbox. I created one while working on a different conversation system, however the new one I implemented was lesser code so I ditch the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a conversation model so you can have a has_many relationship. In this case your problem would be easily solved and the code would make more sense.

If you're reluctant to do that, you can always fetch all the messages with same conversation_id:

```
@messages = Message.where(conversation_id: params[:conversation_id]).order(created_at: :desc)}
```

GL & HF

Comment: Thanks. I changed conversation_id to `id` so it pulls all conversation_id's that matches the message_id the user is on.

Comment: Great that it worked! Your edit suggestion makes the answer confusing as it only applies to your data model, disregarding conventions. (Rails is all over convention).